# Creating Revision for a VCard in Java

Tags: java

Does anyone know how to create the REV, revision, for the VCard?  I looked on Wikipedia and it says combination of date and time, but doesn't really say what the exact method is.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an extract from [RFC2426](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2426.txt) (Section 3.6.4):

**Type name:** REV

**Type purpose:** To specify revision information about the current
   vCard.

**Type encoding:** 8-bit

**Type value:** The default is a single date-time value. Can also be
   reset to a single date value.

**Type special notes:** The value distinguishes the current revision of
   the information in this vCard for other renditions of the
   information.

**Type example:**

```
    REV:1995-10-31T22:27:10Z
    REV:1997-11-15
```